# SuiteCRM install.php is missing

Tags: suitecrm

According to the SuiteCRM install guide, after you've copied all the neccessary files to your webroot directory you are supposed to hit domain/directory/install.php

Unfortunately I am missing the desired install.php file.

I downloaded the fresh `8.4.0.zip`and also one version below.

Do I miss something crucial?

Please refer to the image below, where you can see the contents of my directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following SuiteCRM `7.*` documentation for installation while you have downloaded SuiteCRM `8.*`.

In SuiteCRM 8.*, the `install.php` file is located at the following path:

```
<PROJECT_ROOT>/public/legacy/install.php
```

For SuiteCRM 8.* installation, please use the following documentation:
https://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/admin/installation-guide/downloading-installing/

*(I am not pasting the exact steps as the documentation gets updated frequently and the steps might change)*

Comment: thanks buddy! you were right. Kind of strange, if you download 8.* and click on installation you are pointed to install guide for 7.*